# Graph theory connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I am studying graph thoery and come up with a thought that,

if $G$ is acyclic graph with degree of every vertex is at least two then $G$ is connected!

> The graph is said to be disconnected if at least two vertices of the graph are not connected by a path, otherwise it's said to be connected.

Is this true! if it is then how can I prove that?

All I can imagine is infinite graph which is tree.

(*Degree* of vertex of graph is number of vertices adjacent to that vertex and *acyclic* means graph without cycle).

Comment: Take the disjoint union of two infinite paths. This graph is acyclic of degree two, but not connected. Since every acyclic *finite* graph has at least two vertices of degree one, all your examples will be infinite.

Answer (score 5):

A finite graph in which every vertex has degree $\geq2$ has a cycle, so the statement is vacuously true.  In the infinite, the statement is false, since a forest of two infinite trees is a counterexample.

Comment: Just as a comment to the previous answer. In a finite graph, consider a path $P=v_1-...-v_{n-1}-v_n$ of the maximal length. Since $\operatorname{deg}v_n\geq 2$, $v_n$ is connected with some vertex $u\neq v_{n-1}$. $u$ must be from $P$ (otherwise, we have a contradiction with the maximality). This gives us a cycle.